# Enable Action in navigator popup when nothing is selected

Tags: eclipse-rcp, cnf

I have added an option in eclipse cnf as mentioned below:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
  <objectContribution
        adaptable="true"
        objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject"
        nameFilter="*"
        id="RemoteSync.contribution1">
     <action
           label="Enable RemoteSync"
           class="remotesync.builder.ToggleNatureAction"
           menubarPath="additions"
           enablesFor="1"
           id="RemoteSync.addRemoveNatureAction"
           style="toggle">
     </action>
  </objectContribution>
```

Here enables for is set to 1. So it enables when 1 items is selected. But I want enable the action when nothing in the cnf is selected. What should be the value for enables for?

Answer (score 0):

This can be obtained with: enablesFor="*"

You can know all possible values for 'enablesFor' and their meaning by hovering over the 'enablesFor' in the plugin editor in Eclipse.

Comment: Actually I figured it out. It doesn't work for start. It enables for java.util.collections with count equal to 0 as eclipse provides and empty list when nothing is selected.